# Windows updates fails with error 80070bc9

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, windows-update

My Windows Updates is always failing with error 80070bc9 and tries to restart my computer with this message:

[image: windows update error]

This is really annoying :/ I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 + MS Security Essentials.

Some errors:

```
 {85093ABE-950D-492D-A775-FD58A8F73A16} 2012-08-18 22:57:04:288+0200    1   202 102 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0   AutomaticUpdates    Success Content Install Reboot completed.
{ABF22B98-C1B2-4111-90C4-BF2F9C5F23E4}  2012-08-19 11:25:44:801+0200    1   148 101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   8024a005    AutomaticUpdates    Failure Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x8024a005.
{035C8280-AEAC-4C7D-99F3-3EBEDA7BB69F}  2012-08-19 13:57:18:119+0200    1   148 101 {61CA813A-7585-442E-A66B-B0D15CE6BDC0}  1   80070bc9    SelfUpdate  Failure Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x80070bc9.
{C247868B-CB97-4B3F-9C97-E727644ED486}  2012-08-19 14:04:02:660+0200    1   147 101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0   Microsoft Security Essentials ( Success Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client successfully detected 1 updates.
{ACD1DD67-C577-4C86-A2CE-17E31FFBAD86}  2012-08-19 14:04:38:126+0200    1   162 101 {85FD8DA6-2AD3-495D-97D1-F0F9973F2F27}  100 0   Microsoft Security Essentials ( Success Content Download    Download succeeded.
{CC650378-1CC4-4ABD-AA1E-0C9966D287A7}  2012-08-19 14:04:47:611+0200    1   183 101 {85FD8DA6-2AD3-495D-97D1-F0F9973F2F27}  100 0   Microsoft Security Essentials ( Success Content Install Installation Successful: Windows successfully installed the following update: Definition Update for Microsoft Security Essentials - KB2310138 (Definition 1.131.2339.0)
{D5DDA904-A3B2-48FC-B817-80F3EE2C01F8}  2012-08-19 18:57:27:595+0200    1   148 101 {61CA813A-7585-442E-A66B-B0D15CE6BDC0}  1   80070bc9    SelfUpdate  Failure Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x80070bc9.
{83AC079D-6D2E-4B63-B108-5DD386F965B7}  2012-08-19 23:49:23:993+0200    1   202 102 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0   AutomaticUpdates    Success Content Install Reboot completed.
{4C3B8F7F-39AE-449A-8B54-E7B15B13A680}  2012-08-19 23:49:34:242+0200    1   148 101 {61CA813A-7585-442E-A66B-B0D15CE6BDC0}  1   80070bc9    SelfUpdate  Failure Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x80070bc9.
{FEE6E175-D180-4363-9DFB-5E61077B94FF}  2012-08-20 00:08:16:119+0200    1   202 102 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0   AutomaticUpdates    Success Content Install Reboot completed.
{C8555D1E-3B7B-459B-B4B4-6385DDD078C4}  2012-08-20 11:17:43:985+0200    1   148 101 {61CA813A-7585-442E-A66B-B0D15CE6BDC0}  1   80070bc9    SelfUpdate  Failure Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x80070bc9.
{CFD7D316-4426-4CE7-9EA8-D57357C2C9D9}  2012-08-20 12:10:19:513+0200    1   148 101 {61CA813A-7585-442E-A66B-B0D15CE6BDC0}  1   80070bc9    SelfUpdate  Failure Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x80070bc9.
{D3396DB7-61F0-40C1-A133-E02AB70E877B}  2012-08-20 12:24:34:597+0200    1   202 102 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0   AutomaticUpdates    Success Content Install Reboot completed.
{0E24612F-6148-46B5-9C14-FA1DE860A9AA}  2012-08-20 12:24:45:720+0200    1   148 101 {61CA813A-7585-442E-A66B-B0D15CE6BDC0}  1   80070bc9    SelfUpdate  Failure Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x80070bc9.
{15E41A7F-4067-43A4-B4B7-41C85B39ED36}  2012-08-20 12:39:47:312+0200    1   202 102 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0   AutomaticUpdates    Success Content Install Reboot completed.
{4438E4EC-FB1F-4B7C-A251-D183C865C7AE}  2012-08-20 12:39:56:766+0200    1   148 101 {61CA813A-7585-442E-A66B-B0D15CE6BDC0}  1   80070bc9    SelfUpdate  Failure Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x80070bc9.
{F99AD1BE-768E-46F7-8BAA-8C9ACD7158D4}  2012-08-20 12:41:57:112+0200    1   148 101 {61CA813A-7585-442E-A66B-B0D15CE6BDC0}  1   80070bc9    SelfUpdate  Failure Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x80070bc9.
```

Comment: Have you tried googling that error? About 3,320 results. Have you tried any of the suggestions on those pages? Please update your question to include things you have tried.

Comment: [Windows updates fails with error 80070bc9](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Windows+updates+fails+with+error+80070bc9&sugexp=chrome,mod%3D2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&sei=C18yUJbgNcjyrQeG7YC4CQ&gbv=2).

Comment: None of these solutions work for me. I've tried removing Software Distribution folder, clearing registry keys, reinstalling Windows Update Agent etc.

Comment: Make an edit with this information which doesn't helped you out. It will save your and our time to give the same idea which you have already tried.

Comment: Ok. I will test everything and report here.

Comment: This Windows update tool works sometimes: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058. Also try running 'sfc /scannow' in the command prompt.

Comment: Can you post your update history so we can see when your it started to fail.  My guess this is connected to Microsoft Security Essentials based on log you posted.

Comment: Do a clean boot, then try windows update.

Comment: Runned sfc /scannow and some broken files were found, but they can't be fixed.

Comment: Did a clean boot and this is not fixing the problem. It always force to reboot.

Comment: Sorry, but since I've removed Software Distrubtion folder I don't have updates history. However it's seems that it installed two updates for MS Security Essentials today and yesterday.

Comment: If `sfc/scannow` has found broken files your options are limited.  I would advise installing Windows again, something broke your system, no telling what it was.

Comment: @Spacedust You can try running it a couple times (maybe after rebooting) and see if you get any different results. What files are broken? Did you try the update repair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logon with administrator rights.

Type cmd in the bottom left windows button

I fix it with:

```
fsutil resource setautoreset true c:\
```

Then in safe mode try to delete these files:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd %SystemRoot%\System32\SMI\Store\Machine
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SMI\Store\Machine>attrib -s -h *
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SMI\Store\Machine>del *.blf
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SMI\Store\Machine>del *.regtrans-ms
C:\WINDOWS\system32\SMI\Store\Machine>cd %SystemRoot%\System32\config\TxR
C:\WINDOWS\System32\config\TxR>attrib -s -h *
C:\WINDOWS\System32\config\TxR>del /q *
```

Reboot and it will all work !

Comment: Sadly this did not work for me.  I was not able to delete the files in the config\TxR folder however.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the oldest update first, and do it one at a time to see if that works. I had a similar issue where the Troubleshooter in Control Panel didn't work, installing the System Update Readiness Tool for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB947821) didn't work, and finally just installing each one, one at a time, while a pain in the ass actually got the 4 updates that were failing to install for me after reboot and reverting back to original state to actually install.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you follow the below steps:

1. Disable any Firewall, Antivirus.
2. Manually install the security update from the Microsoft Download Center, and then click Ignore when the error message is displayed.
   Download standalone packages of these updates and install. 
   Download the Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB976098) package now.
3. Re-enable Firewall, Antivirus once the update is installed.
   You may also try resetting Windows Update Components.

To do this:

1. Click on the following link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058
2. Click Run in the File Download dialog box, and then follow the steps in the Fix it wizard.

Comment: Disabling the firewall and anti-virus on an unpatched machine is asking for trouble.