# All Windows 10 updates fail with Error 0x80070bc9

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 7 seamlessly.

Everything works works perfectly that I can see, no crashes at all even when gaming, all completely stable.

Except I cannot install any windows updates whatsoever. I can download them, but not install them:

> There were problems installing some updates, but we'll try again later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact support for information, this may help:
>
> Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1511 for x64-based Systems (KB3140743) - Error 0x80070bc9
>
> Security Update for Adobe Flash Player for Windows 10 Version 1511 for x64-based Systems (KB3135782) - Error 0x80070bc9
>
> Update for Windows 10 Version 1511 for x64-based Systems (KB3139907) - Error 0x80070bc9

That's the message I get when updating through 10's Update & Security program.

Something else that's a bit odd is a discrepancy between viewing my update history in windows 10's settings program and the control panel. Settings reports this:

> Update history
>
> No updates have been installed yet

Whereas if I visit `control panel > programs and features > installed updates` I see two entries under Microsoft Windows:

> Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3133431)
>
> Security Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3124263)

Attempting to uninstall either of these causes the following error:

> Windows Update
>
> An error has occurred. Not all of the updates were successfully uninstalled.

When I shutdown windows rather than shutting down it says:

> Preparing your computer for update

Then shutsdown, then restarts, then says:

> Installing update 35%

And then enters windows, but it hasn't installed the update. It just gets to 35% and then rollsback what it's done, I suppose.

This happens every time I start windows. Very annoying. Inorder to boot windows without this restart every time, I've deleted the downloaded (but not installed) update files from

```
C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download
```

And disabled the windows update service. However, I do want to be able to install updates for security reasons, if nothing else.

To fix any corruption that may have been causing this I've done the following.

As administrator, I've run the following commands:

```
> DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.

> chkdsk /r
and then answered Y to run chkdsk on reboot.
```

I rebooted and I let it run to 100% no problem. No messages given.

```
> sfc /scannow
```

Now here's a weird one, it was able to run a few days ago and reports that it successfully fixed corruption. However, now it returns:

```
There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to complete.  Restart
```

Windows and run sfc again.

It says this even after a clean boot (clean boot achieved by the method I stated above, deleting the update files), so I'm a bit confused why I get this message.

**So what can I do to enable updates?**

Reinstalling windows 10 should fix this. However, all my applications are installed really nicely, and I really like this installation, they way it's all organized ect. I do have two drives `C:` (boot drive), and an `A:` drive. Literally all of my applications are installed on `A:`, and all of the files I've created are also on `A:`.

So is there a pretty safe way to do a fresh install on `C:`, not touch `A:` and have all my programs still work? Maybe though backing up the registry across the reinstall? Or could my registry be causing the update problem?

However, I would really, really, really like it if someone just told be to delete some files, run a command and windows updates work again, as windows seems to be running flawlessly apart from this simple thing!

An answer like this:
[Windows updates fails with error 80070bc9](https://superuser.com/questions/463989/windows-updates-fails-with-error-80070bc9)

But for windows 10. Heck, it's possible that answer would work in 7 and 10 but I'd like some expert's advise.

Here is my update log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e690c56228c15febfd25

Download the logs found at `C:/Windows/Logs` here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g35n1jopvje3orz/AABUBKwBk4h8Cqqv-bdyDt09a?dl=0

Comment: Using Internet Explorer go to this link and download the KB3124263 update and install it manually...http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB3124263

Comment: Then do KB3133431, see if they will install manually. http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB3133431

Comment: You can update to Version 1511 if you have recently performed an upgrade from a previous version of Windows.  If you want to override this behavior use a Version 1511 disk and install the upgrade.  A clean install won't fix this problem, since, it's not required to do so

Comment: 0x80070bc9 = ERROR_FAIL_REBOOT_REQUIRED - The requested operation failed. A system reboot is required to roll back changes made. Share the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS

Comment: have you uploaded the log folder?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Hey I've been away for a few weeks but the problem still exists and you can find my CBS logs at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g35n1jopvje3orz/AABUBKwBk4h8Cqqv-bdyDt09a?dl=0 Thankyou very much if you do look into this

Comment: I see that Windows still needs a reboot to finish a repair operation (from the DISM command). Run **DISM /Online /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions**, reboot and after the reboot try to install the Updates

Comment: @magicandre1981 I get `Error: 50 This operation is only supported against an offline image`. Shall I reboot into Windows recovery partition and run if from the command line there? I'm guessing the image is "online" because it's running? Here's my `dism.log` https://gist.github.com/anonymous/13cced43a76dcbdbc26a

Comment: ok, boot into the recovery options/advanced startup, open cmd.exe and run this: 
**DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions /ScratchDir:C:\**

Comment: @Jay76 did that work?

Comment: do skip the stars (prefix and suffix) if you try magicandre1981's suggestion